# Qlik sense problem with filtering panel and a graph

Tags: qliksense, qlik-expression

I am trying to move the old excel to qlik sense, there is a graphic that is made from the previous day. Then that graph has the dimension of date and measurement has the sum of the amounts per month.
So filtering this by day can be done with a filtering panel, but clicking every day to show me everything can be annoying.

My idea was something like a box where you can enter a value, for example a 6, so when typing a 6 I should show the graph from day 1 to 5.

That is my problem, how could it be done? where can I enter some expression or something to the dimension to calculate the days I want in a simple and intuitive way.

Another idea I had, was to create in qlik sense when preparing the data, a new column that content the sum of the amounts of each day, so that value that I want to show would accumulate

What do you recommend? any help is welcome thanks

Comment: Universal solution is that you create master calendar and then drill down dimension Month-Day so you see data per month and click month to see per day. Please share file so I can prettify that.